# What Permissions are need for List Tags in Microsoft Graph Explorer?

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I am attempting to List Tags:

`https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/ediscovery-case-list-tags?view=graph-rest-beta&tabs=http)`

The Permissions, according to this page are:

`eDiscovery.Read.All, eDiscovery.ReadWrite.All`

I enable these permissions but the query fails with a Permissions error!

I am obviously doing something wrong but cannot determine what.

Can someone help this noob?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please attach the full permission error that you are getting.

Comment: Permissions for the query are missing on this tab. Open the permissions panel to see the full list of Microsoft Graph permissions and select the permission(s) you want and consent to them from there.

Answer (score 0):

Graph Explorer sometimes has not implemented fully some beta API permissions. To add these permissions for https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/ediscovery-case-list-tags?view=graph-rest-beta&tabs=http), you can go to permissions tab and add them manually.

- Click Open Permissions Panel
- Search for eDiscovery
- Select and consent as you need
- Run the API call again.

See screenshot.[image]